# Sub View not showing full screen shows black background

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

I have view in which i have added subView and in subView there is webview problem is that is showing black background at side i want to remove it and make the pdf view in center i am using splitview controller with many detailView controller
I have also add the screen shot of the view

[image]

```
    pdfView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];

    UIWebView*webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,1024,768)];

webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

     NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/1.pdf"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
 [webView loadRequest:request];


[pdfView addSubview:webView];                  
    [webView release];                     
[self.view addSubview:pdfView];
```

Comment: once check in your code is there any where else place black background color in both .m file and xib once check it.

Comment: no on my view in nib i have used i background imageView which 1024,0,1024,748

Comment: i think you used split-view controller first check the frame of pdfview it may be changed at other place. or you have to put Orientation method for the splitview. it is a frame setting problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set its property for Scalling for Fit in Page..

Try :: **`[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];`**

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is coming as shadow of the webView.Trying creating the border color of the webview.and make it white color.Use core graphics for achieving this.

I think it can solve your problem !!